# What ID or other information do you share for Zoom account input on a form

Tags: forms, placeholder

Like many companies during the pandemic, we're building a remote contact service.

We currently get users to put in their preferred remote contact option/service, which includes FaceTime, Google, Skype, or something else.

We want to make "Zoom" a primary option in this list due to it's increasing popularity,  but I've got little experience with Zoom (even after using it a few times) and am not sure what info I'd request in the field placeholder?

Is "Enter your Zoom ID" accurate? Does zoom have ID's?  This information is stored on the users profile so not a one-off thing... Other users would permanently see it on their profile as an option for contacting them remotely.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a question about a software application's feature and not related to its UX design, and therefore it doesn't fit into the requirements for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Enter your Personal Meeting ID" might be the best option.

After watching this video https://youtu.be/3ZLj5GRB6PQ (at 3:50) it seems to be right.

Comment: But why would I want someone having access to my Meeting ID if I haven't scheduled a meeting with them or invited them to something I've setup? Isn't that the exact security risk some companies have been discontinuing Zoom use for?

Answer (score 1):

Zoom doesn't really work like that. The only Zoom IDs are meeting IDs. If you have a pro account you can have a standing meeting ID# but that's not the only meeting ID you'd join meetings for and you definitely wouldn't have people booking meetings with you using your meeting ID. Zooms contact directory is based around email so you could just ask what email they use with their Zoom account.

I have some questions about the use cases of this form. Would I (as a user setting up a meeting) review the contact preferences of those I'm inviting to decide which system to use? What if everyone prefers FaceTime but I have no Apple devices? Does your remote contact service include the ability to book meetings or is it more of a directory. I feel like SKype, Zoom, Google meet are all based around meetings with email invites and meeting IDs. Whereas tools like FaceTime and WhatsApp are calling apps without scheduling functionality. I'm not clear on what use cases or problems you're looking to solve here.